# Combine output score to form a better score

Tags: matlab, prediction

I have ten system perdition outputs only, yes only the outputs.

All outputs are scored by taken RMSE value against ground-truth value:

```
RMSE = sqrt( sum( (true_value(:)-predictions(:)).^2) / numel(true_value))
```

One RMSE for one system, eg: 0.355 for system S who has 1000+ predictions.

From my side of view, without knowing the ground-truth values, how could I make use only the ten outputs and its score to get a better prediction.

Comment: I did not understood entirely your question, but from what I got: get a true prediction error through validation data (not training data) for each, then make a weighted mean with the outputs of each and the validation RMSE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have ten systems with outputs `y_i` and RMSE value of `RMSE_i`, where the index `i` goes from 1 to 10. The linearly weighted output `y` corresponds to:

[image]

In Matlab, the weights for each signal can be obtained with:

```
w = (1-RMSE) ./ sum(1-RMSE);
```

---

For example, if we have RMSE values:

```
RMSE = [0.355, 0.1672, 0.7479, 0.2756, 0.0046, 0.4870, 0.1925, 0.9554, 0.8374, 0.1426];
```

The weights for each signal is:

```
w = [0.1105, 0.1427, 0.0432, 0.1242, 0.1706, 0.0879, 0.1384, 0.0076, 0.0279, 0.1469];
```

It can be seen that outputs with higher RMSE value have lower weight, i.e. their information is less reliable.